# In which case is a thread going to sleep

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Let me give two related questions:

1. Will it sleep when he cant get a lock or mutex lock?
2. Will this leading to context switch when sleep ?

Comment: Well, 'sleep' is a term normally applied to the state of a thread after it has elected to not run for an interval.  Such a call would result in two context switches - when the thread stops running and when it runs again.  Threads blocked on I/O, or some inter-thread synchro like a mutex lock, are not usually described as 'sleeping'.

Answer (score 1):

It will go into sleep state only when we call the sleep method on it.
It will not go to sleep in either of the cases that you specified.